# How can I get a substring from a file path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, filepath

I have a `string path = c:\inetpub\wwwrroot\images\pdf\admission.pdf`

I am using this

```
path = path.LastIndexOf("\\").ToString();
path = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

i want to get:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwrroot\images\pdf
c:\inetpub\wwwrroot\images\pdf\admission.pdf
```

now i want to get the admission.pdf from this `string path` how can i do it?

Comment: You should still use one of the `IO.Path` functions. Doing this manually with `String.Substring` is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string path = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwrroot\\images\\pdf\\admission.pdf";

string folder = path.Substring(0,path.LastIndexOf(("\\")));
                // this should be "c:\inetpub\wwwrroot\images\pdf"

var fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(("\\"))+1);
                // this should be admin.pdf
```

Comment: @safi: No, it didn’t. You should listen to the highest-voted answer.

Comment: @Timwi the OP specifically asked for a solution using Substring in one of his comments and that's why I posted by answer with Substring. Maybe he's got a good reason for that. Thanks for the down-vote.

Comment: Please stop assuming that everyone who comments negatively also downvoted you.

Answer (score 7):

There are a bunch of helper methods on the `System.IO.Path` class for extracting parts of paths/filenames from strings.

In this case, `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` will get you what you want.

Comment: yes but i want to use substring method, not the file path object :)

Comment: Why is that? This method gets you the filename without having to deal with substring and calculating string positions yourself.

Comment: because i am further using this string to rename a file, so some time it might be a folder name as well.

Comment: @safi: You should use `Path.GetFileName` regardless. It works with directory names too.

Answer (score 4):

Why Substring?

Use

```
System.Io.Path.GetDirectoryName(full_filepath)
```

to get the folder name, and

```
System.Io.Path.GetFileName(full_filepath)
```

for just the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Io.Path.GetFileName(path);
```